# How to use replace in div?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have got one question, how to use javascript replace() in div tag? I tried it like that:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="ahoj">ahoj</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.write(document.getElementById("ahoj").replace("ahoj","hola"));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

...but it is not working.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("ahoj")` is an HTMLElement object. Use `document.getElementById("ahoj").innerHTML`

```
document.write(document.getElementById("ahoj").replace(/ahoj/g,"hola"));
```

Or if you don't want a new element:

```
document.getElementById("ahoj").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ahoj").innerHTML.replace(/ahoj/g,"hola");
```

Replace the string and set the innerHTML to the new string. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qesEd/)

Answer (score 0):

I think innerHTML is what you'll need to use.

```
document.write(document.getElementById("ahoj").innerHTML.replace("ahoj", "hola"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById("ahoj");
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/ahoj/g,”hola”);
</script>
```

Comment: Even if your code did work, you would be adding a second element to the page.  I am guessing you want to change an existing element.

It's best to grab that element and then manipulate it.

Note, my solution will not change the ID.   If your aim is to clone the first element changing both ID and InnerHTML, you may want to come up with a more reusable solution; perhaps building the node from scratch or using a template.

Comment: Wait, sorry but i have 1 more question, how to make it replace evary ahoj word? because this will replace just one..
Example: <div id="ahoj">ahoj ahoj ahoj</div>
Result: hola ahoj ahoj
And I want result to be like: hola hola hola...
How?

Comment: Ahh. Sorry about that.  I editted the code to use a global replace regular expression.